# Android studio - Hide filtering listview results

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

```
package test2.gioton.com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */



        if (inputSearch != null)
        {

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                              int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
else{
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }




    }

}
```

This is my main class with the listview adaptaer and the arraylist for the listview names, now my problem is this , when i run my listview filter in my android device it works well for the searching thing, now the problem is that it appears the entire listview before searching something. Like this

[Example image of the listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZGWv.png)

what i want is to display the listview after i start searching in the EditText ... (for example, when i press the first word , the listview appears with the results)

for now my listview only hide , but when i write in the EditText it dosnt show the listview or any results

i need this so badly, thanks in advanced

Comment: Just use condition **if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputSearch.getText()))  { /* hide ListView */  }**

Comment: hi @m0rphine , thanks for let us know, can you explain a little furter the issue ? we are new at list view

Comment: @m0rphine we just added in your if statment what you reply to us, but it appears to not show the results after searching for the first word

Comment: Look @m0rphine , we are not getting the results http://i.snag.gy/VlMMI.jpg